# Play framework (2.3.7) not using my logback configuration

Tags: scala, playframework

I am using Play 2.3.7

I read the documentation here

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/SettingsLogger

I created a file called application-logger.xml (and as logger.xml) under my conf directory

```
<configuration>
    <statusListener class="ch.qos.logback.core.status.OnConsoleStatusListener" />
    <conversionRule conversionWord="coloredLevel" converterClass="play.api.Logger$ColoredLevel" />

    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <file>${application.home}/logs/foo.log</file>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%date - [%level] - from %logger in %thread %n%message%n%xException%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%coloredLevel %logger{15} - %message%n%xException{5}</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <logger name="play" level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </logger>

    <logger name="application" level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </logger>

    <root level="off" />

</configuration>
```

Now I run my play application `activator clean run` and it prints nothing on the console if there is an error. there is no file 'foo.log' created as well.

Based on my reading of the documentation, I thought all my application code will use a logger called "application" and the play internal would use a logger called "play" so if I define appenders for these two loggers I will have everything on console and my file.

But that does not seem to be happening.

I have put the application-logger.xml file in conf directory next to application.conf file.

I also tried renaming my file to logger.xml but still it is just ignored.

Edit::

I even tried to run my application like

```
./activator -Dlogger.resource=logger.xml run
./activator -Dlogger.file=./conf/logger.xml run
```

But nothing can make the play framework pick up that file. nothing.

Comment: Could you please try to replace the path with `${application.home}/logs/foo.log`? Also, please make sure logging is not turned off in your `application.conf` file.

Comment: These are the entries in my application.conf file `logger.root = INFO

logger.play = INFO
logger.application = INFO
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find a solution here

https://www.reddit.com/r/scala/comments/6q6vb3/why_is_it_such_a_big_deal_for_play_framework_to/

Basically when launching the app use the logback configuration setting

so `activator -Dlogback.configurationFile=logger.xml` run`

The play documentation setting `-Dlogger.resource` or `-Dlogger.file` does not work.

Answer (score 1):

This can be the case with custom ApplicationLoader, it require update load with

```
LoggerConfigurator(context.environment.classLoader).foreach {
  _.configure(context.environment, context.initialConfiguration, Map.empty)
}
```

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/SettingsLogger#Using-a-custom-application-loader

Answer (score 0):

I run it from IntelliJ, and with 
`-Dlogger.resource=logback-test.xml` works smoothly.